# Is there a limit to number of groups that can be created in Azure Signal R Services?

Tags: azure, signalr

I am planning to leverage Azure functions and Azure Signal R services for a notification scenario. The number of groups I would need to create could be fairly high ~ 40k+ . Would this work in Azure Signal R Services?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work since the Microsoft documentation says that you can create 1 group per user/connection, so it depends by user limit and not group limit. So if your SignalR service can handle 40k+ users, it will handle 40k+ groups.

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#single-user-groups

Comment: This is the wrong version of SignalR documentation. The new one (ASP.NET Core SignalR) is really different :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction